# GARCH model sensitivity to distribution assumptions

Tags: distributions, model-selection, assumptions, garch, model-comparison

I am trying to fit an ARMA(4,4)- GARCH(1,1) model to return data, where the distribution of returns is highly leptokurtic. I plan to see whether autocorrelations exist in the data even after specifying a GARCH model.

I estimated the GARCH model with different distributional assumptions (Normal, t-distribution and GED) and both the log-likelihood and AIC suggest that a t-distribution with 6 degrees of freedom is the best fit.

However, my problem is that the results in terms of my estimated coefficients are very sensitive to the distributional assumption I use and also to the type of GARCH specification.

Since I would mainly want to interpret the coefficients and not use the model for forecasting I am a bit stuck.

So my questions are:

1. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could mitigate this sensitivity or is it common for GARCH models to have this?
2. Is there a better way to apply the model with the best distribution than just checking different specifications manually?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Given a sufficiently large sample, I do not see a reason to mitigate the sensitivity in the first place. Sensitivity is desirable. It allows the model to reflect regularities in the data, and this is what we use models for (not only GARCH but also more generally).
   On the other hand, if your sample is small and the results vary a lot among similar model specifications, you may be heavily overfitting the data. Try some more parsimonious model specifications instead.
   Also note that ARMA models with different lag orders and different coefficient values can nevertheless produce similar patterns. Thus you may gain more insight by looking at and comparing impulse-response functions (IRFs) of the ARMA models than their coefficient values.
2. I do not think there is. The problem is not specific to GARCH models, however. It is common to a wide range of statistical models.

In summary, I would try different models, assess their assumptions (by running diagnostics on standardized residuals) and pick a model that offers a good trade-off between statistical adequacy (based on diagnostics) and parsimony (based on model complexity). AIC is one measure that can aid you in that.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comprehensive reply! I tried different specifications and the ARMA(4,4) seems to have fit the data the best and left no serial correlation in the errors. Regarding the impulse response functions, is it possible/ sensible to look at them after the GARCH specification? I used Stata and it didn't allow me to do it after the GARCH regression, but I could switch to R if this works better there. Additionally, would you say that my coefficients on the days of the week are consistent (given they did not change much with the type of specification)? Many thanks once again!

Comment: @gberta, regarding IRFs, they can still be quite informative despite the fact that in your case the residuals of ARMA follow a GARCH process instead of being white noise. It is doable in R and probably has been implemented there, but I cannot immediately remember any concrete package/function. Regarding days of the week, you have not mentioned them before. Where in the model do you have them? In any case, the fact that they do not change across specifications does not necessarily imply they are consistent. I would care about a well-approximating specification, not the rest of them.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply again! Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that I also look for day of the week effects and so I included them as dummy variables in the mean equation. Only the Sunday term is significant and it remains significant across every specification, that is why I suspected they likely have some explanatory power. I agree and I try to find the best specification, but even if it has some limitations at least I thought I could mention that these remain significant across all specifications.

Comment: @gberta, that makes sense. Do I understand correctly that your last comment does not contain further questions?

Comment: Yes! I believe I am able to do more analysis now. Thanks very much for all the help!

Comment: @gberta, you are welcome!